# Correct highlighting of code listings using minted

Tags: minted

I've done some coding using Qt and I need to list the code in a document. One of the advantages of Qt is the multiple template classes such as `QList` or `QMap` for example. I'm trying to get the correct syntax highlighting using minted, but can't seem to work out how.

Given all of the templates start with a `Q` is it possible to use regex to match these and highlight them as keywords? The idea comes from [writing Qt in emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/QtMode#toc3), specifically `Q[A-Z][A-Za-z]*`.

Furthermore, is it possible to add other keywords, as Qt also uses `SIGNAL`, `SLOT` and `Q_OBJECT` among others? I know in listings it is possible using the `emph` option.

Example code from the [Qt Website](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html):

```
QMap<QString, int>::const_iterator i = map.constBegin();
while (i != map.constEnd()) {
    cout << i.key() << ": " << i.value() << endl;
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18083. The best option is probably a custom lexer.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like it'll be more hassle than it's worth - I don't quite have the time to get my head around Pygments.

Comment: On an unrelated note, these identifiers are *not* keywords. It may make sense to highlight them but there are also arguments against that, for example the fact that nothing prevents the user from adding their own identifiers starting with `Q` that would not fit into the scheme of Qt classes.

Comment: Any news here? Have you found a solution?