# How can I add words to minted for highlighting?

Tags: minted

I use minted for syntax highlighting

If I give it this C code

```c
int foo () {
   return 123;
}

int bar () {
    int x = foo ();
    ++x;
}
```

it will colour-highlight `foo` in the first line, but later when `foo` is called in the body of `bar`, it will not be coloured.

How can I add `foo` to minted's dictionary so that it will be highlighted everywhere that it appears? Similarly, how can I add the variable `x` to the dictionary so that it will be highlighted in the line `++x`?

The minimum requirement is that all minted usages (`\begin{minted}` or `\inputminted`) will use the same dictionary of function/variable names (per language).

Ideally, code such as `\definecfunction{foo}` could appear anywhere in the document (repeatedly), and all minted usages everywhere would pick it up (presumably this would be a two-pass process). Non-ideally, a full list of symbols could be provided in advance.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: the highlighting is done by the pygments library, using the pygmentize command line, so the natural place to customise anything is there, not in the tex

Comment: See [Add keyword to language in minted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349727/110998) or [How to add custom C++ keywords to be recognized by Minted?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18083/how-to-add-custom-c-keywords-to-be-recognized-by-minted).