# How to you properly specify an alternative to the pygmentize external command for minted?

Tags: minted, pygments

A while ago [I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351184/how-can-i-add-words-to-minted-for-highlighting?noredirect=1#comment862809_351184) how to extend minted to colour-highlight my chosen key words. The consensus was "make the changes in the external pygment program" -- so I did.

The changes are small and the output of my modified pygment program seems to be fine. **If I install my new pygment module system-wide, my document compiles correctly and the changes to syntax highlighting are as expected.**

The catch is I don't want to install my replacement pygment module system-wide, that's too invasive and I want to be able to distribute my document for compilation on other people's computers. I have a simple bash script `bin/pygmentize.sh` which invokes the new version of pygmentize as a set of local scripts. *This bash script is a tested, functioning drop-in replacement for the global `pygmentize` program.* Moreover, when it is invoked via latex/minted in the mannar shown below, it generates the correct markup, but the document fails to compile.

Here's a comparison of the markup that my altered pygmentize generates versus the original:

Before:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{c+cp}{\PYGZsh{}include} \PYG{c+cpf}{\PYGZlt{}stdio.h\PYGZgt{}}

\PYG{k+kt}{void} \PYG{n+nf}{main} \PYG{p}{()}
\PYG{p}{\PYGZob{}}
    \PYG{n+nf}{printf} \PYG{p}{(}\PYG{l+s}{\PYGZdq{}Hello, world!\PYGZdq{}}\PYG{p}{);}
\PYG{p}{\PYGZcb{}}
\end{Verbatim}
```

After:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{c+cp}{\PYGZsh{}include} \PYG{c+cpf}{\PYGZlt{}stdio.h\PYGZgt{}}

\PYG{k+kt}{void} \PYG{n+nf}{main} \PYG{p}{()}
\PYG{p}{\PYGZob{}}
    \PYG{n}{printf} \PYG{p}{(}\PYG{l+s}{\PYGZdq{}Hello, world!\PYGZdq{}}\PYG{p}{);}
\PYG{p}{\PYGZcb{}}
\end{Verbatim}
```

This code was taken from the minted cache directory in both cases, it was generated through latex's invocation of `pygmentize`, not my own manual invocation. (I deleted the minted cache, switched to using my updated pygment, and ran pdflatex again.)

The only difference between the generated markup is that `\PYG{n}{printf}` becomes `\PYG{n+nf}{printf}` so I would expect that the rest of the document would compile the same way. Not so

```
(/tmp/test/minted-cache/D855E0EC6A86300E2FD8FEE675873CCC2C2645CE96B6E2A989A9815
F3192183A.pygtex
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \PYG {c+cp}{\PYGZsh 
                               {}include} \PYG {c+cpf}{\PYGZlt {}stdio.h\PYG...
l.2 ...ude} \PYG{c+cpf}{\PYGZlt{}stdio.h\PYGZgt{}}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This error occurs when compiling the above piece of markup. If I am reading this correctly, it is the `\PYGZsh` command which is not recognised. This error strikes me as very odd -- minted is clearly loading and running, the earlier `\PYG` command *was* recognised as a control sequence, and the error manifests in a section of code which has not changed.

Here's how I got my altered pygmentize to be invoked: poking around in the minted source I saw this:

```
\ifcsname MintedPygmentize\endcsname\else
  \newcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{pygmentize}
\fi
```

Then a little later

```
\MintedPygmentize\space -l #2 -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmerge (...etc)
```

It seems that by defining or redefining `\MintedPygmentize` I should be able to invoke a different program.

I tried doing this before importing minted

```
\newcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{bash bin/pygmentize.sh}
```

and I tried doing this after importing minted

```
\renewcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{bash bin/pygmentize.sh}
```

Either way round produces the error. I have confirmed that my `bin/pygmentize.sh` is invoked, and that it is receiving its inputs and producing its outputs.

I have concluded that redefining `\MintedPygmentize` has caused some black magic side effects.

**So, in order to have a portably-compilable document, how do I tell the minted package to use my external script to generate the markup in a way that doesn't cause strange errors like this to appear?**

Comment: `bash bin/pygmentize.sh` is wrong to begin with, because it would work only for documents in the parent directory of `bin`. Maybe `bash \string~/bin/pygmentize.sh`?

Comment: Nah, the script knows its place and handles paths correctly.

Comment: For what it’s worth you should *not* modify `pygmentize` itself (and that wasn’t the recommendation). Rather, you should write a plugin for Pygments (and that’s what David meant). Unfortunately I don’t know of a way to load Pygments plugins locally without installing them system-wide. So in the end it’s possible that your approach is the only working one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `\renewcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{bash bin/pygmentize.sh}` is not working for you is due to how the `pygmentize` check is implemented in minted.

[This line](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/c6cd4452d8a3e97ac0109a99e2a8110113a25810/source/minted.dtx#L3754) is what executes the check on non-windows systems (e.g., linux, macOS):

```
    \immediate\write18{which #1 && touch \jobname.aex}
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.aex}
     {\AppExiststrue
      \DeleteFile{\jobname.aex}}
     {\AppExistsfalse}
  \fi}
```

Your custom command then gets expanded to:

`which bash bin/pygmentize.sh && touch \jobname.aex`

Which finds bash, but not `bin/pygmentize.sh`. The solution is to either make `bin/pygmentize.sh` executable (`chmod u+x bin/pygmentize.sh`) so that `which` does not return an error or to bypass the check completely. You can bypass the check by declaring your command as:

```
\renewcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{which ; bash bin/pygmentize.sh}
```

This will get expanded to: `which which; bash bin/pygmentize.sh && touch \jobname.aex`, and will thus pass the check. On actual invocations, `which ;` does not produce any output so the whole command invocation will behave as if this part of the command is not there.