# Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package, while Pygments is already installed?

Tags: minted, python, pygments

Installed MacTex2023 on a new Mac and all is well except for a nagging issue with "pygmentize" that I've already installed. I cannot find how to adjust system to recognise the installed "pygmentize" that exists in my "/Users//Library/Python/3.9/bin" folder.

I have upgraded to Python 3.11 and used pip3 to confirm that Pygments 2.14.0 is installed.

I've already checked those SE pages that discuss Pygmentize issues, e.g. at [Pygmentize not working properly with minted package in TexShop on OS X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279214/pygmentize-not-working-properly-with-minted-package-in-texshop-on-os-x/281188#281188)

Additional specs via 'pip3 list':
Package    Version

---

1. altgraph   0.17.2
2. future     0.18.2
3. macholib   1.15.2
4. pip        23.0.1
5. Pygments   2.14.0
6. setuptools 67.6.0
7. six        1.15.0
8. wheel      0.40.0

Note: When I run the following minimal LaTeX package, I see the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{c}
    int main() {
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
    }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

e.g.: 'Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.'

Note 2: I Typeset to LaTeX using TexShop.

Comment: Did you compile with the `-shell-escape` flag? That is necessary for the package to work.

Comment: @Amarakon - Thanks for the question. In the `TeXShop preferences > Engine > pdfTeX > Latex` field I have the following command: `pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape`, which I assume turns ON the `-shell-escape` flag ... n'est pas? Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Yep, that should do it.

Comment: @Amarakon - Thank you! The whole `-shell-escape` flag issue took me a bit to research ... now I need to research a bit more to address the issue with `pygmentize` .... unless someone else has had the same issue, and a solution. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I ran into the same problem using LuaLatex. The strange thing was the work around I discovered in trial-and-error: first compile with PDFLatex (be aware of the use of `fontspec` / `fontenc` differences between the two), which generated the required `minted` output. Then compile again with LuaLatex to get the final PDF. I am using TeXStudio/MikTeX (fully upgraded). Checking the pathways in both compilations revealed a strange issue: in LuaLatex the whole pathway was replaced with only one line pointing towards the MikTeX installation....

Comment: @alchemist - Thank you so much for your response. I should have mentioned that I Typeset to LaTeX using TexShop. I went through much the same rigamarole with `pygmentize` a few years back (even made notes in the code re the issue). Now with the new Mac, I'm back to square one. I've upgraded to MacTeX2023, so there are two variables at play. I'll likely have to stumble around for a bit before I stumble on a solution as I apparently did back then. All-in-all a small price to pay for the power of LaTeX ... hadn't thought about `fontspec` ... don't know if/how relevant ... will have to check that!

Comment: `fontspec` isn't relevant to the `pygemtize` issue, only you use it to manage fonts in LuaLatex.

Comment: @alchemist - Thank you for the clarification ... saved me a bit of time ... still working on other issues at the moment, but thank you for clarifying and removing one item from my todo list!

Comment: are you sure you want --shell-ecape on in your default settings rather than enabled per document? Be _very_ careful of running any tex code coped from elsewhere, eg this site. You are giving the author of that code full access to your machine.

Comment: @David Carlisle - Thank you for the comment (always a special privilege), and NO, I do NOT want to give ANY author full access to my machine. Any references or thoughts to guide me toward enabling my settings to instead be `per document` would be appreciated ... A special thanks again!

Comment: I don't use texshop but I believe you can use its `% !TeX` magic comment feature at the top of the document to make such settings

Comment: have you tried to launch a Terminal and type ``pygmentize -V`` to confirm it is correctly installed?

Comment: have you tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281188/293669

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried all sorts of `% !TeX` and never could get it to activate shell-escape.  Unfortunately https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586661 advises people to add permanently `--shell-escape` to `pdflatex` invocation in TeXShop preferences.

Comment: @RosesBouquet ``ln -s "$(which pygmentize)" /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize`` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281188/293669 works for me (I don't need sudo due to my custom way of installing TeXLive on my mac).  But I still have no solution how to tell TeXShop to use ``--shell-escape`` only of one run.  My advise: better to stop using TeXShop than to configure permanently with ``--shell-escape``.

Comment: @user691586 well personally I would not do that and if texshop doesn't have a built in comment i'd set up a separate menu option to choose that, just as you can presumbly choose between lualatex and pdflatex, or set it up to use arara which can confgure this from a comment or (what I actually do) just run such thing from the commandline and literally type `pdflatex --shell-escape documentname`

Comment: @user691586 ooh it has a manual:-)  https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/TeXShopManual-2006.pdf   TeXShop now provides a different protection. A preference item under the Engine
tab is labeled “Shell Escape Warning”. This item is off when TeXShop is delivered. If
the item is on and “shell-escape” is active, then the first time a file is typeset during
a TexShop session, a warning dialog will appear allowing you to turn shell-escape off
for that particular file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oops there was a temporary black-out and I missed your comment while concentrating on posting my answer...

Comment: @user691586 no I was hit by same so my comment actually posted after  your answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle indeed if you both add ``--shell-escape`` in the default TeXShop pdflatex call and toggle on the "Shell Escape Warning" you will be warned about shell-escape.  But the logic is moot.  Much better if there was  some toggle in the TeXShop window to turn on, exceptionally the ``shell escape``.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `--shell-escape` but rather with TeXShop being able to locate `pygmentize`. Open a Terminal and type `ln -s ~/miniconda3/bin/pygmentize /usr/local/bin/pygmentize`, replacing the first path with that appropriate for your setup, and hit `return`. You should then be able to process your document assuming you enable `--shell-escape` in any of the usual ways. I prefer to put `% !TEX parameter = --shell-escape` at the top of my file.

Comment: @user691586 - apologies for the delay in responding ... Re `pygmentize -V` the response I get is `Pygments version 2.14.0, (c) 2006-2022 by Georg Brandl, Matthäus Chajdas and contributors.`

Comment: @RosesBouquet ok this thus means pygmentize is there.  But TeXShop will not find it if it is not also among the TeXLive binaries hence the ``ln -s "$(which pygmentize)" /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize`` business. cf my answer.  Unfortunately it seems, at least for TeXShop of 5 or 6 years ago that you need to permanently add ``--shell-escape`` but you  have possibilty to toggle "warn if shell escape" (or whatever is wording) and you can deactivate for documents not needing it, on first compilation.

Comment: @user691586 - OK, I see the `Omit Shell Escape` message ... but if I select OK (to keep Shell Escape) ... something is not working ... I'll need some time to sort out ... Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Any thoughts, comments or experience with the `minted alternative`?  (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351454/how-to-you-properly-specify-an-alternative-to-the-pygmentize-external-command-fo

Comment: @RosesBouquet It works for me if I have done (once, in a Terminal) `ln -s "$(which pygmentize)" /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize`,  then in TeXShop `Preferences>Engine` (I assume in English) in the `pdflatex` invocation I add `--shell-escape`,  and also toggle ``Shell escape warn`` (I see it in my locale language) but only because I want to have opportunity to *deactivate*  shell-escape. Then I launch compilation, a pop-up appears asking if I really want to use shell-escape, I click `OK` and it works.

Comment: @user691586 - OK, I selected `pdflatexc` under `Macros>Claus Gerhardt Macros`, but I needed to run the script twice to obtain the complete output. (A bit strange?) Question: Does the `pdflatexc` script set `--shell-escape` ON for just the immediate project, or for ALL projects. Thank you for this ... I will need to test the `pdflatexc` script on my full project b4 accepting your answer ... Thank you for all your research!!

Comment: `pdflatexc` is simply `pdflatex --shell-escape`.  I.e. it only uses `--shell-escape` once, when called.  It does not have any left-over effects.  However personally I would not use it because I need to see the console output of LaTeX run for quick analysis in case of errors or warnings, and this window is not shown by TeXShop when one uses it.

Comment: @user691586 - Interesting how the `pdflatexc` script console output appears blank ... until suddenly the finished PDF appears ... as you pointed out, would be nice to actually see the output of LaTeX run ... a small price to pay ... n'est pas? Thank you for confirming that `pdflatexc` only uses `--shell-escape` once ... any thoughts as to why I needed to run the `pdflatexc` twice to get the full PDF output? Thanks again for all your research!!

Comment: @user691586 - FWIIW, I ran `sudo ln -s "$(which pygmentize)" /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize`, then in TeXShop `Preferences>Engine` in the pdflatex invocation I added `--shell-escape`, and also toggled the Shell escape warning ON ... Thank you again for all your research!!

Comment: @user691586 - `which pygmentize` works!

Comment: @user691586 - Duplicate runs fixed ... my error ... Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Re your `are you sure you want --shell-ecape on in your default settings rather than enabled per document?`, where may I research what `--shell-escape` really means ... and `You are giving the author of that code full access to your machine.` ... that is certainly NOT something I wish to do ... Thanks again for ALL your comments and assistance!

Comment: @RosesBouquet it allows a tex document that I send you, or you copy from some website to run `\write18{arbitrary commands}` so anything you can do on the command line could happen, All your files could be deleted, your ssh private keys could be emailed to me, or the tex file could process normally and a pdf gets made.

Comment: the same is true if you copy  a shell script or executable program, but they are "obviously risky" but normally running latex on a document isn't risky at all.

Comment: @David Carlisle - As one of the champions of LaTeX and TeX  in general I take notice of your messages. I did just enough research (e.g. not much, but enough) of the `--shell-escape` issue. Recent documents (which I cannot locate at the moment) call for avoiding the use of `--shell-escape` in MacTeX 2023. I've realized that bypassing the many protections built into TeX and LaTeX was a risky endeavor, but the nail in the coffin was my realization that my project ran just fine w/o the Minted package, which was the reason why I was attempting to implement the `--shell-escape` feature all along.

Comment: @David Carlisle - I will leave `--shell-escape` in my TeXShop for now, while typesetting w/o `--shell-escape`, with the intent to delete it from my TeXShop setup once I've had enough experience with my projects running w/o the `--shell-escape` function. Thank you David Carlisle for pointing this out from the get-go when I originally posted on SE ... your points about having complete access to my system bothered me for the better part of a week ... with the clincher being that `your ssh private keys could be emailed to me`. 'nuf said. Thank you!!

Comment: @David Carlisle - for some reason, my LaTeX project fails to create any glossaries w/o `minted` and `--shell-escape`. I've tried setting the `minted` option to `draft=true`, but the glossaries still fail unless I include `--shell-escape`. Seems I've been running with `minted` and `--shell-escape` for so long that I've forgotten how to create the glossaries w/o them. I've tried searching for combinations of `minted`, `--shell-escape` and `glossaries` but have found nothing relevant to the issue. What am I missing?

Comment: What does `minted` and `--shell-escape` have to do with `glossaries`?

Comment: minted is completely unrelated. shell-escape could be related if you generate your glosary via a non standard command that you call via write18

Comment: @David Carlisle - Re: `minted is completely unrelated.` - Just what I thought ... Not using `write18` that I know of ... I've never heard of `write18` b4 your mentioning it ... Best I can tell there is nothing out of the ordinary with my glossaries that I'm using ... but let me research this a bit more and advise as to what I can see ... It all seems a bit odd ... In the meantime, I've removed all mention of `--shell-escape` from my projects ... Many thanks for the advice and feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka (I wish this would have been easier, e.g. from [this TeXShop
page](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/changes_3.html)).

Caveat: I tested this with a TeXShop 3.89 which is nowadays an old version.

To let TeXShop use `--shell-escape` for only one specific document you can:

- instead of hitting "Compile" (or whatever is English word), go to `Macros>Claus Gerhardt Macros` and then choose `pdflatexc`.  It launches the compilation using `--shell-escape` flag.  (I discovered that by digging into `~/Library/TeXShop/bin/`).

I tried many `% !TeX` variants such as `% !TEX TS-program="pdflatex --shell-escape"` but this fails, and perhaps there is a parameter `TS-program-options` but I stopped my search after above workaround.

But first you also need that TeXShop finds pygmentize.

An answer is given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281188/293669 which worked for me.

On my installation (which is a direct TeXLive install) I do not need the `sudo` so simply

```
ln -s "$(which pygmentize)" /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize
```

in Terminal.

Perhaps execute first `which pygmentize` and `pygmentize -V` to confirm it
is correctly installed, prior to symlink it to the directory where TeXShop
finds TeX binaries.  The above should apply on MacTeX based installations.
For direct TeXLive installations on (old) Macs, replace
`/Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize` by something such as
`/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy/pygmentize`.

Comment: Sadly, the ``Macros>Claus Gerhardt Macros>pdflatexc`` method wll not display nor update the console showing output to terminal from the pdflatex run.

Comment: Understood ... Thank you for this option, and for ALL your research!!

Answer (score 1):

The pygmentize issue can be addressed by installing pygments with pip2.

```
sudo pip2 install pygments
```

This method works on my cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. I realised that `pdflatex` relies on Unix/Linux command line utility called `which` to confirm, that `pygmentize` is available. I didn't have it installed on my system and LaTeX compilation aborted with the same error you mentioned above:

```
You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.
```

In my case installing `which` resolved the problem. Be attentive and do not repeat my mistake.