# How can I assign a node name while wrapping minted environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minted

I was thinking how can I frame particular pieces of `minted` environment for `beamer` slides. I had a choice either to use overlays and split code across several blocks ( [Beamer vs. Minted: overlays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26917/beamer-vs-minted-overlays) ) or just to draw some frame on top. I feel like the second should be a bit better though it would require some absolute coordinates for selection to roughly match code.

I've read
[Wrapping minted in a Tikz box with a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41162/wrapping-minted-in-a-tikz-box-with-a-command) and it works just fine, however I'd like to be able to refer to each node by some unique name. For instance the following allows me to refer to a single minted block later as *a*.

```
\renewenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{lrbox}{\minted@bgbox}
  \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}}
 {\end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \tikz\node[text width=\linewidth,] (a) %mintedbox,
         {\usebox{\minted@bgbox}};
 }

%\newmint[jscode]{javascript}{}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
```

So I can have later something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw (a.north west) rectangle ++(2cm,-1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like it to be less hard-coded. Is it possible to pass a name into that `\renewenvironment` definition via somehow redefined `minted` or something?

If there are better alternatives to point into particular fragments of `minted` environment on `beamer` slides, I'd be interested.

Comment: You can create a new counter to unique the node.

Comment: It kind of works.

Would you mind sharing an idea if it is possible to utilize \label and if possible use different coordinate system of tikz such that I naturally use line numbers instead of _cm_ in vertical direction?

It would complete the way to put an emphasis on parted of _minted_ block.

Comment: Another question relates to coordinates calculation as using corners is not that exciting. I can use tikz calc library for that. However I wonder if the following can be less verbose to mark a couple of lines in the middle of _minted_ block:

`\draw ($(minted1.north west)-(0cm,5cm)$) rectangle ++($(minted1.east) - (minted1.west) - (0cm,1cm)$);`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Would you be willing to put up a small example? I think the OP forgot to ping you with `@` character :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below I define a new counter. In this way it is possible to unique every node. The node-number can be printed by setting the command:

```
\showmintedcountertrue
```

In this case the node name will be printed in the right margin.

```
% !TEX program  = pdflatex -- shell-escape
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[]{minted}

\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{mymintedcounter}
\newif\ifshowmintedcounter
\edef\minted@resetoptions{\minted@resetoptions\def\minted@opt@bgcolor{foo}}
\renewenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{%
  \noindent\stepcounter{mymintedcounter}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\minted@bgbox}
  \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}}
 {\end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \tikz\node[text width=\linewidth] (a-\themymintedcounter) 
         {\usebox{\minted@bgbox}%
           \ifshowmintedcounter\hfill\rlap{\quad\themymintedcounter}\fi
         };
 }
\makeatletter

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]


%\showmintedcounterfalse
\showmintedcountertrue

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}[]{javascript}
a=b;
\end{minted}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw (a-\themymintedcounter.north west) rectangle ++(2cm,-1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```