# Editing math.py for pygment

Tags: minted, matlab

I'm using the minted package to syntax my code. When I'm doing so in I'm using the Matlab language. When to continue on the next line, we do so in Matlab by entering `...` before the next row. However, the output in the pdf marks the actual row with a red square.

Now I'm inside the Matlab lexer math.py file and looking for way to add `...` to be accepted and not to be treated as an error in my code. How should I put it?

Currently inside minted:

```
\begin{minted}[frame=lines, framesep=3mm, linenos=true, mathescape]{matlab}
function X = c(a, b,...
    c)
\end{minted}
```

The dots above yields the red square.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Added relevant code.

Comment: The issue isn't related to `...` -- You are getting the highlighting of an error -- a missing brace.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: That error doesn't show up in Matlab. Shouldn't the code be the same inside minted-syntaxing?

Comment: Normally yes. The issue is related to this one: [Red box drawn around question-mark operator in minted Erlang code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14166/red-box-drawn-around-question-mark-operator-in-minted-erlang-code).

Comment: I've already been there. But my question is how I should write to allow '...' inside that file.

Comment: You can write your matlab code as follows `function X = c(a, b,... %)`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I need it to have it in that way, simply because otherwise the row is wider than the pdf document. But that yields that red square error in the pdf.

Comment: I'm closing as off-topic: the lexer part of `minted` is not really TeX at all, so is not something we can help with.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).